# Drawing 3D Surface

Tags: graphing-functions, 3d

I would like to know to plot this kind of 3D surface as depicted below. Anybody help plot it, give me suggestions to choose an appropriate pc program for this matter???https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Book%3A_Calculus_(OpenStax)/15%3A_Multiple_Integration/15.3%3A_Double_Integrals_in_Polar_Coordinates
[image]

Comment: You could start by trying GeoGebra 3D calculator, for example...

Comment: @matti: GeoGebra 3D is easy to use but it's x,y and z axis styles are not nice as in this picture. And I hope anybody here have some other options. I do wonder what (open or commercial) program used to produce this graphic.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax for essential part of the problem, so that it's searchable.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Answer (score 0):

You may try searching "desmos 3d", and you would find an array of 3D graphs represented on a 2D plane.

Here's [my graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/q9y2ghbeh9)
originally from [another graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nqom2ih05g).

In the example, input your explicit function in terms of $x$ and $y$, followed by a constraint enclosed with braces.  In your example, that would be $\{(x-1)^2+y^2 \ge 1\}$.

[image]

Comment: Nice! It is another plotter which is quite similar to GeoGebra 3D. I still hope there is another program produce for illustrative graphic as in the question :) Thank for pointing out to the option